# Realocação de item na chave do array

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde!
Apesar de ter pesquisado sobre o assunto e procurado na documentação, ainda não consegui chegar a  uma solução para o seguinte problema..
Tenho um array trazido do banco com títulos e itens.

O array me vem da seguinte forma:

```
$a[0] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo1",
    "item" => "item 1",
];
$a[1] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo 2",
    "item" => "item 2",
];
$a[2] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo 2",
    "item" => "item 3",
];
```

Meu objetivo é transformar esse array em um novo, com os itens já realocados, exemplo:

```
$limpo[0] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo1",
    "item" => "item 1",
];
$limpo[1] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo 2",
    "item" => "item 2",
    "item" => "item 3,
];
```

Ou seja, os títulos não irão se repetir.

Até o momento, montei o código da seguinte forma..

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {

    if($key>0){
        $comparacao = ($a[$key-1]["titulo"]);   
        echo($comparacao."<br>");
    }

    if($key==0){
    $limpo[$key] = [
        "titulo" => $value['titulo'],
        "item" => $value['item']
    ];
    }else if($value["titulo"] != $comparacao){
        $limpo[$key] = [
        "titulo" => $value['titulo'],
        "item" => $value['item']
    ];
    }
    else if($value["titulo"] == $comparacao){

        //array_push($limpo[($key-1)]['item'], $value['item']);

        $limpo[($key-1)] = [
        "titulo" => $value['titulo'],
        "item" => $value['item']
    ];
    }
}
```

Porém, no momento em que cai em `($value["titulo"] == $comparacao)`, o "item 3" é alocado no lugar do item 2, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
$limpo[0] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo1",
    "item" => "item 1",
];
$limpo[1] = [
    "titulo" => "titulo 2",
    "item" => "item 3",
];
```

Teria alguma forma de fazer o push na posição anterior? O trecho com push comentado está retornando um erro por indicar a posição anterior..

Abraços.

Comment: Você não consegue ter duas chaves com o mesmo nome no mesmo nível.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o título como índice do array já que são únicos. Assim é fácil testar se o título já existe. Se existir adiciona o item a um array, senão cria o título. Ex.:

```
<?php

$limpo = [];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    $titulo = $a["titulo"];

    if (! isset($limpo[$titulo])) {
        $limpo[$titulo] = [
            "titulo" => $a["titulo"],
            "item" => [ $a["item"] ],  // cria uma array de items
        ];
    } else {
        $limpo[$titulo]["item"][] = $a["item"];  // adiciona item ao array
    }
}

/* print:

    [
    'titulo 1' => [
        'titulo' => 'titulo 1',
        'item' => ['item 1']
    ],
    'titulo 2' => [
        'titulo' => 'titulo 2',
        'item' => ['item 2', 'item 3']
    ]
]

*/
```

[Código funcionando...](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/GraveSelfassuredMatter)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou certinho dentro da classe, mas ao tentar jogar na view, recebo o seguinte erro "expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", seria necessário converter para string? Pensei em usar algo como json_encode mas o retorno vem vazio..

Comment: Provavelmente você vai precisar usar um for pra printar isso na tela... Se a resposta te ajudou e você achar que ela é a solução., Pode marcar ela como correta.

Comment: Já votei amigo, mas apareceu um alerta sobre ter menos de 15 pontos de reputação, aparentemente ele foi computado mas não sera exibido. Obrigado pelas dicas, grande abraço!

Comment: Sem problemas.. eu esqueço ar limitações de reputação.. não quis ser chato. Que bom que ajudou :D